# Python script refuses to execute when called with PHP

Tags: php, python

I am trying to run a python script through a PHP page that is supposed to scrape a few websites (using scrapy if that helps). The program takes no arguments, and is supposed to write the results into a database. Running this python script alone works with no issues. However trying to run it from PHP, it simply does not do anything and the values in my database never update.

I have tried combinations of exec, shell_exec and escapeshellcmd with no luck. I have tried redirecting the output (the script prints log information on standard output, but I am not interested in this info) to dev/null. I have tried to add a print statement to the end and waiting for output, but nothing still happens. I have both tried to run it in the background regardless of the PHP page I am on, or waiting for the program to finish before redirecting. EDIT: Removing the redirect doesn't help, if I do that, the code still simply doesn't execute.

This is my current code in it's simplicity:

```
set_time_limit(900);

$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/bin/python /path/to/file/script.py > /dev/null &');

shell_exec($command);
//function to redirect to the next page
redirect('arguments');
```

I am hoping to make the script run in any way at all, whether to wait for output or run it to completion in the background - at this point the most important thing is to just have the script run. I am not very experienced with PHP so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the user running PHP doesn't have execute permission on the py script.

Comment: I made sure the file has full permissions for everyone.

Comment: For starters, you might replace `> /dev/null` with `>>lets_see_what_python_says.txt 2>&1`

Comment: Hi, I tried that as well - file just shows up empty.